# How to show data table in report viewer in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, datatable, reportviewer

I have a report viewer with the name reportviewer1.A report named as report.rldc. I have used the following code to Get data and into a data table. Now i want to show the data table's data in the report viewer.
            The code is mentioned below. Please help :(

```html
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.TableName = "Report showing result for                 " +   
ComboBoxCategory.SelectedItem.ToString()+" +  
ComboBoxQueryChoice.SelectedItem.ToString() +" from " + 
dateTimePickerStarting.Value.ToString()+" to "+dateTimePickerEnding.Value.ToString();
table.Clear();
dataadapter.Fill(table);
```

The command text is

```
SELECT Distinct Sale.Product_ID , S_Article , 
    S_Size , SUM(S_Quantity) AS QuantitySold,SUM(Profit) AS Profit 
FROM Product,Sale 
WHERE Product.Product_ID=Sale.Product_ID 
and(S_Date between (@Startdate) 
and (@Enddate))" + SelectedCateogry + 
" Group By Sale.Product_ID,(S_Article),(S_Size) 
Order BY Profit DESC"
```

Comment: Take a look at your code and pay attention to the portion(s) where you have `+` wrapped withing `" "` did you step through the code ..? also what are you trying to do in regards to building a sql statement..

Comment: @MethodMan Yeah i would fix the + thing. I have a sale table from which i want to show some data Via Query stored in command.

Comment: what is the command text.. I am going to post a simple way of how you can use `Datatable SqlConnection, SqlDataAdapter, and the Fill Method`  use this as a template and change my answer to fit your case.. 
also after you call the .Fill method you need to assign the ReportViewer's datasource = dataadapter; then if needed call the reportviewer.Refresh() method. I am posting an example of how to load the datatable to get you started..

Comment: The command text is

SELECT Distinct Sale.Product_ID , S_Article , S_Size , SUM(S_Quantity) AS QuantitySold,SUM(Profit) AS Profit FROM Product,Sale WHERE Product.Product_ID=Sale.Product_ID and(S_Date between (@Startdate) and (@Enddate))" + SelectedCateogry + " Group By Sale.Product_ID,(S_Article),(S_Size) Order BY Profit DESC"

Comment: you need to format the sql properly in regards to wrapping your text around `" "` I would personally make this a stored procedure and use Parameters as well

Comment: Ok sir i would try that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ConnString = System.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconn"].ConnectionString;
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter;
DataTable someDataTable = new DataTable("ReportViewResults);
using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("yourStoredProc or Sql Query", connStr))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;//change to Text if your passing sql string
        dataadapter= new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(someDataTable);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "ReportViewResults" ? in
 DataTable someDataTable = new DataTable("ReportViewResults);

Comment: it's the same as you doing the table.Name property but why assign it in a separate line when you can do it at the `Constructor` level..if you are not sure about some of these basic things then do a msdn google search on `DataTables` what I have provided you is pretty self explanatory and works in regards to filling a datatable..

Comment: How would i fill the report viewer with this datatable

Comment: you need to look at the datasource property of the Reportviewer.. if you are not sure do a google search on ReportViewer... thanks